# How to automate JAVA form opened through .JNLP file

Tags: forms, jnlp

automate JAVA form

I have a scenario where a  dot jnlp file gets downloaded on clicking a button in firefox browser ,I need to access and automate this java form.I am able to open the file using automation ,but accessing element is difficult .So is there any tool which we can use to automate JAVA form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am currently creating an end to end automated scenario, that requires to: launch a Java desktop application through JNLP; from this application a window will be launched  application built with OracleForms;